# contenteditable selection of text not working

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I am faced with following: when I try to select text in a `contenteditable` element and the end of the selection is the start of the element content, then no select event is fired and there are no `Selection` and `Range` objects.

Could somebody please give me any advice on why this might occur or how I can prevent this?

Code responsible for getting selection range:

```js
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').bind("mouseup keyup touchend", function() {
  lastCaretIndex = getSelectionRange();
});

function getSelectionRange() {
  var sel;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();

    console.log(sel); // this doesn't print anything event empty string

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      return sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
  } else if (document.selection) {
    return document.createRange();
  }

  return null;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-input" contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL9z0bvu/) (open your browser console to make sure that selection doesn't get logged).

[image: GIF illustrating the steps to reproduce the issue]

Comment: This question would be much better with [example code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you post it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or as a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), we can immediately see what code you are using, and start from there.

Comment: @phihag Hello, I have added code responsible for getting user selection range

Comment: Please create a working code sample showing the problem you are facing. I'm sure the `unction()` above in your code sample want work and I just don't want to dig trough typos ...

Comment: @caramba I have added jsfiddle link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you only log selection changes when specific events occur on the `contenteditable` element. More specifically, you have

```
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').bind("mouseup keyup touchend", // ...
```

In particular the `mouseup` event will normally be triggered when the selection changes. Except when it doesn't. When you release the mouse outside of the editable `div` (which you do in your example!), then the `div` will never receive a `mouseup` event and thus never log the selection.

There are two ways around this:

1. Listen for events on the entire `body`. Downsides are that you receive more events that do not influence the selection and that it is still possible to get `mouseup` events outside of the page.
2. Listen for the [`selectionchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange) event.

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>
```

You can of course still access the selection as you currently do inside this event handler. This event is triggered every time the selection changes, so you may want to [throttle](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) it.

Full implementation of that can be found below.

```js
function handler() {
  // do whatever you want here
  // this shows the selection and all ranges it consists of
  var sel = window.getSelection(),
      ranges = Array(sel.rangeCount).fill(0).map((_, i) => sel.getRangeAt(i));
  ranges = ranges.map((r) => `${r.startOffset}-${r.endOffset}`).join(';');
  console.log(`Selection [${ranges}:"${sel.toString()}"]`);
}

function throttle(func) {
  var timeoutId = false,
      called = false,
      wrap = function() {
        if (!called) {
          clearInterval(timeoutId);
          timeoutId = false;
        } else {
          func();
        }
        called = false;
      };
  return function() {
    if (timeoutId === false) {
      func();
      timeoutId = setInterval(wrap, 500);
    } else {
      called = true;
    }
  };
}

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', throttle(handler));
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: oh, not it's clear why this issue occurs. thank you a lot, now I will try to use document listener instead

Comment: @excluded I just updated my answer to include a demo of the throttling as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual code works perfectly and logs a [**Selection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object in the console, even if the end of the selection is the start of the element content.

Indeed you need to log this `Selection` text instead of logging the whole `object` which reflects the whole Selection object changes for each event.

I updated your snippet to log the text of the selection using `Selection.toString()`, you can see it working here:

```js
$('div[contenteditable="true"]').bind("mouseup keyup touchend", function() {
  lastCaretIndex = getSelectionRange();
});

function getSelectionRange() {
  var sel;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();

    console.log(sel.toString()); // this doesn't print anything event empty string

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      return sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
  } else if (document.selection) {
    return document.createRange();
  }

  return null;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-input" contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379408/3669624), it shows and explains the perfect way to get text selection.